# Нужно скачать архив с google drive и разархивировать его

Tags: c#, winforms, google-drive

Есть простой код для скачивания архива с гугл диска:

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.DownloadFile("https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=", SubPath);
```

(id вырезал, subpath - путь до нужной папки).

И дело в том, что если я перехожу по прямой ссылке через браузер - все скачивается, а программа не хочет скачивать файл. Это я чего-то не понимаю, или как?

Также хочется, чтобы программа могла распаковывать запаролленый архив (при этом зная пароль, разумеется). Поискал в интернете - ничего толкового не нашел. Расширение архива - 7z

Comment: Нажмите в браузере Ctrl+Shift+N, откроется "Приватное окно", вот в нем вставьте эту ссылку, начнет загрузку? Я вот лично сейчас залил файл на свой диск, расшарил его, получил ссылку, подставил в ваш код ID и спокойно скачал мой файл обратно на компьютер, а это значит что? Правильно, это значит то, что ваша ссылка битая, файл который вы пытаетесь скачать либо не прошел проверку на вирусы и там выдается предупреждение, либо файл вообще не для публики а только для вас, либо вовсе ошиблись с ID. И да, облако использовать не лучшая идея, оч нестабильное, и блокирует после N (~100)  загрузки файл.

Comment: Ну и последнее, `WebClient` является устаревшим в C#, об этом нынче вон даже IDE всякие начинают говорить. Используйте `HttpClient`.

Comment: только что попробовал в приватном окне - все скачалось.

на счет последнего учту.

Comment: Ну, тогда я вам могу сказать просто - **не воспроизводится**.